# sails.js v0.11.0 assets not being copied

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I'm new to node.js, sails.js and grunt.js.

When I run "sails lift" it does not create the .tmp folder and copy the assets to that folder.

However, when I run "grunt" in the project folder, the .tmp folder does get created and the assets do get copied over.

Anyone have suggestions on how to fix so "sails lift" works without calling "grunt"?

Comment: Can it be that you are running sails in production mode?

Comment: When I run "sails lift" the debug output says: "Environment : development"

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `sails` process has the right privileges and you're not running short of space.

Also, try manually deleting the `.tmp` folder and lifting again. Sometimes there can be issues with automatic file removal if any of the files are in use.